# string select and append to another string

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file (FreshPIN.txt) contain lots of pin code in each line; I need a bash script to select one of the pin, print it out, and then remove it from the source file, adding it to end of another file (usedPIN.txt).

FreshpPIN.txt is like:

```
========
1111111111111111
2222222222222222
3333333333333333
....
nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn
========
```

before it prints, I should be asked to enter a number from 0 to 31 and put the number in the command below:

```
at&g**00**=xtd*788*1111111111111111#
```

in above example `at&g`  and `=xtd*788*` should be stable in all output commands.

Comment: So, if the user asks to select pin number 2 and the number is 8, for instance, the output line should be `at&g**08**=xtd*788*2222222222222222#` and `2222222222222222` should be appended to `usedPIN.txt`?

Comment: Just use any language you like to, 1. read all the lines, 2. random pick one, 3. truncate the file and print out the remains down, 4. repeat it

Comment: can you provide concrete details about what you need to do ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You are expected to show some effort in your question, showing what you've done and explaining what your problems are and asking for help fixing the problems.  What have you tried?  What caused you problems?

Answer (score 0):

```
fresh=FreshPIN.txt
used=usedPin.txt
echo "Please key in"
read key
pin=`head -1 "$fresh"`
printf '%s\n' "$pin" >>"$used"
sed -i~ 1d "$fresh"
printf 'at&g%s=xtd*788*%s\n' "$key" "$pin"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
#!/bin/bash

fresh=FreshpPIN.txt
used=usedPIN.txt
max=31

die() {
    echo >&2 "$@"
    exit 1
}

# Get a random pin
pin=$(sed -n '/[[:digit:]]\+/p' -- "$fresh" | shuf -n1)
[[ "$pin" ]] || die "No more pins in file \`$fresh'"

echo "Pin chosen: $pin"

# Prompt user:
while read -e -r -p "Enter a number between 0 and $max (q to quit): " n; do
   if [[ "$n" = q ]]; then
       echo "Aborting. Pin $pin remains in file \`$fresh'."
       exit 0
   elif [[ "$n" != +([[:digit:]]) ]]; then
      echo "Not a valid number. Try again."
   elif ((10#$n>max)); then
      echo "Number must be between 0 and $max. Try again."
   else
      break
   fi
done

# Guard if read fails (e.g., if user presses Ctrl-D)
[[ "$n" ]] || die "Something went wrong."

# Delete this pin from file
ed -s -- "$fresh" <<EOF
/^$pin\$/d
wq
EOF

# Save pin in file
printf >> "$used" "%s\n" "$pin"

# Output:
printf "at&g**%02d**=xtd*788*%s\n" "$((10#$n))" "$pin"
```

It's quite robust (the user must really enter a number between 0 and 31, and it won't be messed up if user enters, e.g., `09`). Uses `ed` to delete old pin from file `FreshpPIN.txt`: very efficient (no auxiliary file or ugly stuff using `sed -i`). Uses good bash practice overall. Uses `shuf` to get a random pin (don't need to compute the number of lines and hack ugly stuff around to get a random pin). `sed` is used to select only pins from file `FreshpPIN.txt`, so you can leave your header, comment, etc. in there.